# Hung Tasks in EXT4 on VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

On my VM, when an IO intensive task starts, like launching an Android Emulator as part of a Jenkins CI Android build/test task, I get hung tasks in my VM:

```
[ 1200.360041] INFO: task flush-8:0:137 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1200.361987] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1200.365915] flush-8:0       D ffff88006c813780     0   137      2 0x00000000
[ 1200.365919]  ffff8800374f2e20 0000000000000046 0000000000000246 ffff88006a3c2100
[ 1200.365921]  0000000000013780 ffff880037485fd8 ffff880037485fd8 ffff8800374f2e20
[ 1200.365923]  ffff8800374855d0 ffff8800374855d0 ffff8800674fb130 ffff88006c813fd0
[ 1200.365926] Call Trace:
[ 1200.365932]  [<ffffffff8134ecc1>] ? io_schedule+0x59/0x71
[ 1200.365936]  [<ffffffff81199946>] ? get_request_wait+0x105/0x18f
[ 1200.365940]  [<ffffffff8105fcd3>] ? add_wait_queue+0x3c/0x3c
[ 1200.365942]  [<ffffffff8119a8a5>] ? blk_queue_bio+0x17f/0x28a
[ 1200.365944]  [<ffffffff811993d2>] ? generic_make_request+0x90/0xcf
[ 1200.365946]  [<ffffffff811994e4>] ? submit_bio+0xd3/0xf1
[ 1200.365950]  [<ffffffff81120b5b>] ? __bio_add_page.part.12+0xcc/0x1ed
[ 1200.365953]  [<ffffffff810bbfae>] ? test_set_page_writeback+0xdc/0xeb
[ 1200.365965]  [<ffffffffa00aef5f>] ? ext4_io_submit+0x21/0x4a [ext4]
[ 1200.365969]  [<ffffffffa00af185>] ? ext4_bio_write_page+0x1fd/0x3bc [ext4]
[ 1200.365972]  [<ffffffff811be833>] ? __percpu_counter_add+0x2d/0x49
[ 1200.365976]  [<ffffffffa00abd86>] ? mpage_da_submit_io+0x2bd/0x36f [ext4]
[ 1200.365981]  [<ffffffffa00adad0>] ? mpage_da_map_and_submit+0x2e3/0x2f9 [ext4]
[ 1200.365984]  [<ffffffffa00addcd>] ? write_cache_pages_da+0x214/0x2c5 [ext4]
[ 1200.365990]  [<ffffffffa00ae120>] ? ext4_da_writepages+0x2a2/0x45d [ext4]
[ 1200.365993]  [<ffffffff81199eab>] ? queue_unplugged+0x71/0x84
[ 1200.365998]  [<ffffffff81118717>] ? writeback_single_inode+0x11d/0x2cc
[ 1200.366000]  [<ffffffff81118b97>] ? writeback_sb_inodes+0x16b/0x204
[ 1200.366003]  [<ffffffff81118c9d>] ? __writeback_inodes_wb+0x6d/0xab
[ 1200.366005]  [<ffffffff81118e03>] ? wb_writeback+0x128/0x21f
[ 1200.366007]  [<ffffffff811192fd>] ? wb_do_writeback+0x189/0x1a8
[ 1200.366009]  [<ffffffff811193a1>] ? bdi_writeback_thread+0x85/0x1e6
[ 1200.366011]  [<ffffffff8111931c>] ? wb_do_writeback+0x1a8/0x1a8
[ 1200.366014]  [<ffffffff8105f681>] ? kthread+0x76/0x7e
[ 1200.366016]  [<ffffffff81356ef4>] ? kernel_thread_helper+0x4/0x10
[ 1200.366019]  [<ffffffff8105f60b>] ? kthread_worker_fn+0x139/0x139
[ 1200.366020]  [<ffffffff81356ef0>] ? gs_change+0x13/0x13
[ 1560.364036] INFO: task rs:main Q:Reg:1828 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1560.366045] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1560.368128] rs:main Q:Reg   D ffff8800677681c0     0  1828      1 0x00000000
[ 1560.368132]  ffff8800677681c0 0000000000000086 ffff88006c5c9d00 ffff880036ea0ab0
[ 1560.368134]  0000000000013780 ffff8800666e3fd8 ffff8800666e3fd8 ffff8800677681c0
[ 1560.368136]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd7c60 ffff880049cde128
[ 1560.368139] Call Trace:
[ 1560.368145]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[ 1560.368154]  [<ffffffffa0095660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[ 1560.368158]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[ 1560.368165]  [<ffffffffa00ae5b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[ 1560.368167]  [<ffffffffa0095911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[ 1560.368174]  [<ffffffffa00ce263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[ 1560.368178]  [<ffffffffa00acb5e>] ? ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x37/0x7a [ext4]
[ 1560.368182]  [<ffffffff8102bb7c>] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0x42/0xb2
[ 1560.368185]  [<ffffffffa00acc09>] ? ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x68/0x1da [ext4]
[ 1560.368189]  [<ffffffffa00ae59e>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x14/0x45 [ext4]
[ 1560.368194]  [<ffffffffa00c36d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[ 1560.368198]  [<ffffffffa00ae5b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[ 1560.368201]  [<ffffffffa00ae58a>] ? ext4_evict_inode+0x2af/0x2af [ext4]
[ 1560.368205]  [<ffffffff811174b3>] ? __mark_inode_dirty+0x22/0x17a
[ 1560.368208]  [<ffffffff8110caad>] ? file_update_time+0xda/0x105
[ 1560.368211]  [<ffffffff810b5fec>] ? __generic_file_aio_write+0x160/0x278
[ 1560.368214]  [<ffffffff8103b013>] ? ttwu_do_wakeup+0x50/0xc4
[ 1560.368216]  [<ffffffff8134fdc7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0xe/0xf
[ 1560.368218]  [<ffffffff8103f6aa>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x187/0x197
[ 1560.368220]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[ 1560.368222]  [<ffffffff810b6161>] ? generic_file_aio_write+0x5d/0xb5
[ 1560.368226]  [<ffffffffa00a6bd4>] ? ext4_file_write+0x1e1/0x235 [ext4]
[ 1560.368228]  [<ffffffff8134fdc7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0xe/0xf
[ 1560.368231]  [<ffffffff8123e6bd>] ? uart_write+0xd9/0xe9
[ 1560.368233]  [<ffffffff81070ff2>] ? arch_local_irq_restore+0x2/0x8
[ 1560.368236]  [<ffffffff810fa378>] ? do_sync_write+0xb4/0xec
[ 1560.368237]  [<ffffffff8134fdc7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0xe/0xf
[ 1560.368240]  [<ffffffff8122abbc>] ? n_tty_write+0x311/0x344
[ 1560.368242]  [<ffffffff8102bb7c>] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0x42/0xb2
[ 1560.368245]  [<ffffffff81164949>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x2d
[ 1560.368247]  [<ffffffff810faa69>] ? vfs_write+0xa2/0xe9
[ 1560.368249]  [<ffffffff810fac46>] ? sys_write+0x45/0x6b
[ 1560.368251]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 1560.368263] INFO: task mktemp:2705 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1560.369941] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1560.372899] mktemp          D ffff88006c813780     0  2705   2704 0x00000000
[ 1560.372902]  ffff880036ea11a0 0000000000000082 ffffffff00000000 ffffffff8160d020
[ 1560.372904]  0000000000013780 ffff8800687effd8 ffff8800687effd8 ffff880036ea11a0
[ 1560.372906]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd9460 ffff880069e57908
[ 1560.372909] Call Trace:
[ 1560.372912]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[ 1560.372916]  [<ffffffffa0095660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[ 1560.372919]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[ 1560.372922]  [<ffffffffa0095911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[ 1560.372927]  [<ffffffffa00ce263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[ 1560.372932]  [<ffffffffa00b0f2d>] ? add_dirent_to_buf+0x120/0x271 [ext4]
[ 1560.372936]  [<ffffffffa00b197f>] ? ext4_add_entry+0x541/0x90d [ext4]
[ 1560.372939]  [<ffffffffa00a8715>] ? ext4_new_inode+0xbd4/0xc6b [ext4]
[ 1560.372943]  [<ffffffffa00b1d61>] ? ext4_add_nondir+0x16/0x5c [ext4]
[ 1560.372947]  [<ffffffffa00b1fcb>] ? ext4_create+0xea/0x12f [ext4]
[ 1560.372950]  [<ffffffff81104a15>] ? vfs_create+0x66/0x88
[ 1560.372952]  [<ffffffff81102a2d>] ? d_alloc_and_lookup+0x3a/0x60
[ 1560.372954]  [<ffffffff81105459>] ? do_last+0x25b/0x58d
[ 1560.372956]  [<ffffffff81105d83>] ? path_openat+0xce/0x33a
[ 1560.372959]  [<ffffffff810ce865>] ? pte_offset_kernel+0x16/0x35
[ 1560.372961]  [<ffffffff811060b1>] ? do_filp_open+0x2a/0x6e
[ 1560.372963]  [<ffffffff8134ea6c>] ? _cond_resched+0x7/0x1c
[ 1560.372965]  [<ffffffff811b4589>] ? __strncpy_from_user+0x18/0x48
[ 1560.372968]  [<ffffffff8110ee37>] ? alloc_fd+0x64/0x109
[ 1560.372970]  [<ffffffff810fa07d>] ? do_sys_open+0x5e/0xe5
[ 1560.372971]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 1680.372053] INFO: task rs:main Q:Reg:1828 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1680.373820] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1680.375718] rs:main Q:Reg   D ffff8800677681c0     0  1828      1 0x00000000
[ 1680.375721]  ffff8800677681c0 0000000000000086 ffff88006c5c9d00 ffff880036ea0ab0
[ 1680.375724]  0000000000013780 ffff8800666e3fd8 ffff8800666e3fd8 ffff8800677681c0
[ 1680.375726]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd7c60 ffff880049cde128
[ 1680.375729] Call Trace:
[ 1680.375735]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[ 1680.375744]  [<ffffffffa0095660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[ 1680.375748]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[ 1680.375755]  [<ffffffffa00ae5b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[ 1680.375757]  [<ffffffffa0095911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[ 1680.375764]  [<ffffffffa00ce263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[ 1680.375768]  [<ffffffffa00acb5e>] ? ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x37/0x7a [ext4]
[ 1680.375771]  [<ffffffff8102bb7c>] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0x42/0xb2
[ 1680.375777]  [<ffffffffa00acc09>] ? ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x68/0x1da [ext4]
[ 1680.375789]  [<ffffffffa00ae59e>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x14/0x45 [ext4]
[ 1680.375794]  [<ffffffffa00c36d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[ 1680.375798]  [<ffffffffa00ae5b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[ 1680.375801]  [<ffffffffa00ae58a>] ? ext4_evict_inode+0x2af/0x2af [ext4]
[ 1680.375805]  [<ffffffff811174b3>] ? __mark_inode_dirty+0x22/0x17a
[ 1680.375808]  [<ffffffff8110caad>] ? file_update_time+0xda/0x105
[ 1680.375811]  [<ffffffff810b5fec>] ? __generic_file_aio_write+0x160/0x278
[ 1680.375814]  [<ffffffff8103b013>] ? ttwu_do_wakeup+0x50/0xc4
[ 1680.375816]  [<ffffffff8134fdc7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0xe/0xf
[ 1680.375818]  [<ffffffff8103f6aa>] ? try_to_wake_up+0x187/0x197
[ 1680.375820]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[ 1680.375822]  [<ffffffff810b6161>] ? generic_file_aio_write+0x5d/0xb5
[ 1680.375826]  [<ffffffffa00a6bd4>] ? ext4_file_write+0x1e1/0x235 [ext4]
[ 1680.375828]  [<ffffffff8134fdc7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0xe/0xf
[ 1680.375831]  [<ffffffff8123e6bd>] ? uart_write+0xd9/0xe9
[ 1680.375833]  [<ffffffff81070ff2>] ? arch_local_irq_restore+0x2/0x8
[ 1680.375836]  [<ffffffff810fa378>] ? do_sync_write+0xb4/0xec
[ 1680.375837]  [<ffffffff8134fdc7>] ? _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore+0xe/0xf
[ 1680.375840]  [<ffffffff8122abbc>] ? n_tty_write+0x311/0x344
[ 1680.375842]  [<ffffffff8102bb7c>] ? pvclock_clocksource_read+0x42/0xb2
[ 1680.375844]  [<ffffffff81164949>] ? security_file_permission+0x16/0x2d
[ 1680.375847]  [<ffffffff810faa69>] ? vfs_write+0xa2/0xe9
[ 1680.375848]  [<ffffffff810fac46>] ? sys_write+0x45/0x6b
[ 1680.375850]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 1680.375863] INFO: task mktemp:2705 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1680.377292] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1680.378852] mktemp          D ffff88006c813780     0  2705   2704 0x00000000
[ 1680.378855]  ffff880036ea11a0 0000000000000082 ffffffff00000000 ffffffff8160d020
[ 1680.378857]  0000000000013780 ffff8800687effd8 ffff8800687effd8 ffff880036ea11a0
[ 1680.378860]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd9460 ffff880069e57908
[ 1680.378862] Call Trace:
[ 1680.378864]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[ 1680.378868]  [<ffffffffa0095660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[ 1680.378871]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[ 1680.378874]  [<ffffffffa0095911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[ 1680.378879]  [<ffffffffa00ce263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[ 1680.378883]  [<ffffffffa00b0f2d>] ? add_dirent_to_buf+0x120/0x271 [ext4]
[ 1680.378887]  [<ffffffffa00b197f>] ? ext4_add_entry+0x541/0x90d [ext4]
[ 1680.378891]  [<ffffffffa00a8715>] ? ext4_new_inode+0xbd4/0xc6b [ext4]
[ 1680.378894]  [<ffffffffa00b1d61>] ? ext4_add_nondir+0x16/0x5c [ext4]
[ 1680.378898]  [<ffffffffa00b1fcb>] ? ext4_create+0xea/0x12f [ext4]
[ 1680.378901]  [<ffffffff81104a15>] ? vfs_create+0x66/0x88
[ 1680.378911]  [<ffffffff81102a2d>] ? d_alloc_and_lookup+0x3a/0x60
[ 1680.378913]  [<ffffffff81105459>] ? do_last+0x25b/0x58d
[ 1680.378915]  [<ffffffff81105d83>] ? path_openat+0xce/0x33a
[ 1680.378917]  [<ffffffff810ce865>] ? pte_offset_kernel+0x16/0x35
[ 1680.378919]  [<ffffffff811060b1>] ? do_filp_open+0x2a/0x6e
[ 1680.378921]  [<ffffffff8134ea6c>] ? _cond_resched+0x7/0x1c
[ 1680.378924]  [<ffffffff811b4589>] ? __strncpy_from_user+0x18/0x48
[ 1680.378926]  [<ffffffff8110ee37>] ? alloc_fd+0x64/0x109
[ 1680.378928]  [<ffffffff810fa07d>] ? do_sys_open+0x5e/0xe5
[ 1680.378930]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 1920.376046] INFO: task rm:2740 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 1920.377518] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 1920.379205] rm              D ffff88006c813780     0  2740   2704 0x00000000
[ 1920.379209]  ffff880036ea0ab0 0000000000000086 ffff880000000000 ffffffff8160d020
[ 1920.379211]  0000000000013780 ffff880066e37fd8 ffff880066e37fd8 ffff880036ea0ab0
[ 1920.379214]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd9460 ffff880069e57908
[ 1920.379216] Call Trace:
[ 1920.379223]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[ 1920.379232]  [<ffffffffa0095660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[ 1920.379236]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[ 1920.379239]  [<ffffffffa0095911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[ 1920.379244]  [<ffffffffa00b129e>] ? ext4_find_entry+0x214/0x298 [ext4]
[ 1920.379251]  [<ffffffffa00ce263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[ 1920.379254]  [<ffffffffa00b07f4>] ? ext4_delete_entry+0x82/0x137 [ext4]
[ 1920.379259]  [<ffffffffa00c36d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[ 1920.379263]  [<ffffffff8113bfa2>] ? __dquot_initialize+0x1d/0xfe
[ 1920.379267]  [<ffffffffa00b314c>] ? ext4_unlink+0x12e/0x1ee [ext4]
[ 1920.379270]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[ 1920.379273]  [<ffffffff81104bb4>] ? vfs_unlink+0x68/0xbb
[ 1920.379275]  [<ffffffff81105aae>] ? do_unlinkat+0xd0/0x156
[ 1920.379278]  [<ffffffff81350335>] ? page_fault+0x25/0x30
[ 1920.379280]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 2400.376055] INFO: task java:2342 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 2400.377813] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 2400.379840] java            D ffff88006c813780     0  2342   2053 0x00000000
[ 2400.379845]  ffff8800677a8830 0000000000000082 ffff880000000000 ffffffff8160d020
[ 2400.379849]  0000000000013780 ffff880067505fd8 ffff880067505fd8 ffff8800677a8830
[ 2400.379852]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbdc460 ffff880069e57eb8
[ 2400.379855] Call Trace:
[ 2400.379863]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[ 2400.379873]  [<ffffffffa0095660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[ 2400.379877]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[ 2400.379880]  [<ffffffffa0095911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[ 2400.379888]  [<ffffffffa00ce263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[ 2400.379892]  [<ffffffffa00acb5e>] ? ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x37/0x7a [ext4]
[ 2400.379897]  [<ffffffffa00b2805>] ? ext4_orphan_add+0xac/0x1a4 [ext4]
[ 2400.379900]  [<ffffffffa00b3196>] ? ext4_unlink+0x178/0x1ee [ext4]
[ 2400.379903]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[ 2400.379907]  [<ffffffff81104bb4>] ? vfs_unlink+0x68/0xbb
[ 2400.379909]  [<ffffffff81105aae>] ? do_unlinkat+0xd0/0x156
[ 2400.379912]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[ 2640.376043] INFO: task first-boot:2815 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 2640.378126] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 2640.380282] first-boot      D ffff88006c813780     0  2815   2806 0x00000000
[ 2640.380286]  ffff880036dce0c0 0000000000000082 0000000000000000 ffffffff8160d020
[ 2640.380289]  0000000000013780 ffff880066e03fd8 ffff880066e03fd8 ffff880036dce0c0
[ 2640.380291]  0000000000000246 ffffffff8134fd89 ffff88006cbd3460 ffff880069e57828
[ 2640.380293] Call Trace:
[ 2640.380300]  [<ffffffff8134fd89>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x9/0x25
[ 2640.380309]  [<ffffffffa0095660>] ? do_get_write_access+0x1ad/0x36a [jbd2]
[ 2640.380314]  [<ffffffff8105fcfd>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x2a/0x2a
[ 2640.380320]  [<ffffffffa00ae5b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[ 2640.380323]  [<ffffffffa0095911>] ? jbd2_journal_get_write_access+0x21/0x38 [jbd2]
[ 2640.380329]  [<ffffffffa00ce263>] ? __ext4_journal_get_write_access+0x4f/0x5e [ext4]
[ 2640.380333]  [<ffffffffa00acb5e>] ? ext4_reserve_inode_write+0x37/0x7a [ext4]
[ 2640.380337]  [<ffffffffa00acc09>] ? ext4_mark_inode_dirty+0x68/0x1da [ext4]
[ 2640.380341]  [<ffffffffa00ae59e>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x14/0x45 [ext4]
[ 2640.380346]  [<ffffffffa00c36d8>] ? ext4_journal_start_sb+0x139/0x14f [ext4]
[ 2640.380349]  [<ffffffffa00ae5b4>] ? ext4_dirty_inode+0x2a/0x45 [ext4]
[ 2640.380353]  [<ffffffffa00ae58a>] ? ext4_evict_inode+0x2af/0x2af [ext4]
[ 2640.380357]  [<ffffffff811174b3>] ? __mark_inode_dirty+0x22/0x17a
[ 2640.380360]  [<ffffffffa00ad06d>] ? ext4_setattr+0x2f2/0x377 [ext4]
[ 2640.380363]  [<ffffffff8104b2a6>] ? current_fs_time+0x31/0x37
[ 2640.380365]  [<ffffffff8110e393>] ? notify_change+0x1cb/0x293
[ 2640.380368]  [<ffffffff81036628>] ? should_resched+0x5/0x23
[ 2640.380370]  [<ffffffff810f94f8>] ? do_truncate+0x68/0x86
[ 2640.380372]  [<ffffffff810f91ca>] ? __dentry_open+0x1cd/0x2c2
[ 2640.380374]  [<ffffffff811056b7>] ? do_last+0x4b9/0x58d
[ 2640.380376]  [<ffffffff81105d83>] ? path_openat+0xce/0x33a
[ 2640.380378]  [<ffffffff810ce865>] ? pte_offset_kernel+0x16/0x35
[ 2640.380380]  [<ffffffff811060b1>] ? do_filp_open+0x2a/0x6e
[ 2640.380382]  [<ffffffff8134ea6c>] ? _cond_resched+0x7/0x1c
[ 2640.380385]  [<ffffffff811b4589>] ? __strncpy_from_user+0x18/0x48
[ 2640.380387]  [<ffffffff8110ee37>] ? alloc_fd+0x64/0x109
[ 2640.380389]  [<ffffffff810fa07d>] ? do_sys_open+0x5e/0xe5
[ 2640.380391]  [<ffffffff81354d92>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

They always seem to be related to EXT4 and building temp files.  I moved the dir in /tmp that jenkins writes to off to a separate disk, thinking that space was the issue.  I still get the problem, and it results in me having to reboot the server via the developer console.

Comment: What is the size of your disk? You need big disks to get good I/O-performance. Otherwise you only get good I/O-performance in "bursts".
I got the same problem some weeks ago when I was testing the I/O performance and reported a bug here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=73

Comment: @Emil - There's no way that the I/O limits of the disk should cause hung tasks though.  A hung task would be ALL I/O from a process blocked for 120 secs - this would be more in line with a virtual disk controller issue, not I/O throttling - even 1 IOPS would prevent a Hung Task.  Thanks for the link though, I am adding my dmesg to your bug report for more reporting data.

Comment: I tested I/O performance on both small disks (<= 10 GB) and large disks (200 GB). It always hung on the small disks but never on the large disks, when I benchmarked I/O. That's at least my results...